# How to create an optional interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have this case:

```
interface IRenderComponent {
  urlToHideAt?: string;
  links?: IInternalNavbarLink[];
  currentLink?: IInternalNavbarLink;
}
const renderComponent = ({ urlToHideAt, links, currentLink }: IRenderComponent) => {
```

And it kind of makes sense. I am setting all children as optional, but in doing this, I get an error each time I try to use the function,

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)

Which makes sense. I set the props as optional, not the one param.

My question, then, is how to set the whole argument `{ urlToHideAt, links, currentLink }`  as optional. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [default parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters):

```
const renderComponent = ({ urlToHideAt, links, currentLink }: IRenderComponent = {}) => {}
```

If the caller doesn't pass the first parameter, it will default to `{}`, which is a valid `IRenderComponent`, and `urlToHideAt`, `links`, `currentLink` will all be `undefined`. (`{}.links === undefined`)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the interface optional but you can give a default value to the first argument of ˋrenderComponentˋ to make it optional:

```
const renderComponent = ({ urlToHideAt, links, currentLink }: IRenderComponent = {}) => {
    // Do something
}
```